# java generics: runtime type-checking to determine a strategy

Tags: java, generics, types

how may I select a different method based upon a Generic type?

Simply I have a class parametrized with a generic type and I have to select the correct PreparedStatement setter according to the T type:

```
Class CustomFieldsTypeManager<T> {
   ArrayList<T> data;

   public void setUpStatement(PreparedStatement st){
      ...
      if ( **T==String** ){
         st.setString(index, (String) data<T>.get(dt_index);
      } else if ( **T==Integer** ){
         st.setInt(index, (String) data<T>.get(dt_index);
      }
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `instanceof`:

```
if ( data.get(dt_index) instanceof String ) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: @user2224731 please mark the post as the answer by clicking on the check below the rep.

Comment: The only caveat is with 'non object types' (such as int) whose belongs to Object so the type-check to Integer fails.

The solution is to force cast to T the getter (data.get).

[Maybe this info can help someone with the same issue in the future]

Comment: @user2224731 A `List<T>` doesn't support `int` but `Integer`.

Comment: Yes I known, primitive types are not supported by generics

Comment: Got it! the error depends on this **fieldValues.add((T) new Object());** which I used to initialize an empty list. This because I don't know how to create a new generic instance of T. It works, but I need to force cast to T when I get something out of the array.

Answer (score 4):

Because of type erasure that information on generics is lost at runtime. You should try to exploit parametric polymorphism in a different way, by providing specialization of the classes:

```
class CustomFieldsTypeManager<T> {
   ArrayList<T> data;

   abstract void setUpStatement(PreparedStatement st);
}

class StringCustomFieldsTypeManager extends CustomFieldsTypeManager<String> {
   void setUpStatement(PreparedStatement st) {
     st.setString(index, data.get(dt_index)); // data it's already an ArrayList<String>
   }
}
```

There are also ways to check it at runtime but this kinda defeats the good points of generics an inheritance even if they're as safe as this solution (must they must be correctly written).

Comment: I already solved using instanceof, thank you anyway. I like your design solution. Is very intresting

Answer (score 0):

You can't. But what you could do, is:

```
class CustomFieldsTypeManager<T> {
    private Class<T> type;
    public CustomFieldsTypeManager(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
CustomFieldsTypeManager<String> m = new CustomFieldsTypeManager<String>(String.class);
```

And finally:

```
public void setUpStatement(PreparedStatement st) {
    if (type.equals(String.class)){
        st.setString(index, (String) data<T>.get(dt_index);
    } else if (type.equals(Integer.class)){
        st.setInt(index, (String) data<T>.get(dt_index);
    }
}
```

Or, simply use the `PreparedStatement#setObject` method instead of the ones you're using.

Comment: Gosh. I didn't noticed there where such a method... I've already solved with the instanceof ... but thanks anyway i'll remember for the future